# Sorting disrupts the changing of nr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the sorting of a Javascript list. The list that is created when a text area is filled and a grading is chosen. It looks like this:

```
var element = '<li class="lista">' + filmen + '<span class="betyg">' + changeNumber(grade) + '</span></li>';
film_list.append(element);
```

I also have a function that converts the number in the span element to stars, it looks like this:

```
function changeNumber(number) {
  var stars = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    stars += "*";
  }
  return stars;
}
```

The problem is that there are two buttons to sort the list, high and low depending on the grade, and when I push the buttons the list is sorted correctly. However, the stars disappear and the numbers turn up again. I have tried to call the function `changeNumber` from the sorting button but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I should use as the argument. Any suggestions as to what I should do?

The sorting function looks like this:

```
var button_high = $('#high');
var betyg_array = new Array();
button_high.click(function () {
  $list = $("#filmerna ul");
  $("#filmerna ul li")
    .remove();
  betyg_array.sort(function (x, y) {
    return y[1] - x[1]
  });
  $.each(betyg_array, function () {
    $nyFilm = $("<li />");
    $nyFilm.attr("class", "lista")
    $nyFilm.text($(this)[0]);
    $nyBetyg = $("<span />");
    $nyBetyg.attr("class", "betyg");
    $nyBetyg.text($(this)[1]);    
    $nyBetyg.appendTo($nyFilm);
    $nyFilm.appendTo($list);
    changeNumber();
  });
});
```

Comment: In your last line of code, nothing is passed to `changeNumber` and the result (`stars`) is ignored.

Comment: if you read my question thats exactly what I ask, what should I pass as argument in the function changeNUmber()

Comment: solved the problem if anyone is interested, I updated the code with the two lines of code needed...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question, and, when you're able, accept that answer.

Comment: @spovell—it wasn't clear to me what you were asking. In your answer, you should delete the last line of code (`changeNumber();`) as it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var button_high = $('#high');
var betyg_array = new Array();
button_high.click(function () {
  $list = $("#filmerna ul");
  $("#filmerna ul li")
    .remove();
  betyg_array.sort(function (x, y) {
    return y[1] - x[1]
  });
  $.each(betyg_array, function () {
    $nyFilm = $("<li />");
    $nyFilm.attr("class", "lista")
    $nyFilm.text($(this)[0]);
    $nyBetyg = $("<span />");
    $nyBetyg.attr("class", "betyg");
    $nyBetyg.text($(this)[1]);
    var stars = $nyBetyg.text(betyg_array); //this line and the line below was the solution
    $nyBetyg.text(changeNumber(stars)); 

    $nyBetyg.appendTo($nyFilm);
    $nyFilm.appendTo($list);
  });
});
```